# Groupby by index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

How can I use groupby by indexes (1,2,3)(they all are in the same order) and get the sum of the column score belonging to the range of each indexes? Basically I have this:

```
    index  score
    1      2
    2      2
    3      2
    1      3
    2      3
    3      3
```

What I want:

```
    index  score  sum
    1      2      6
    2      2      9
    3      2
    1      3
    2      3
    3      3
```

I understand it has to be something like this :

```
    df = df.groupby(['Year'])['Score'].sum()
```

but instead of a Year, to somehow do it by indexes?

Comment: also "score" is not the only column there is

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0)['Score'].sum()` or `df.groupby(level=0).sum()` where level=0 is the index.

Comment: yes but I need the sum of the group of indexes, the sum of 1st 123 = 6 and the second 123 = 9 , and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the comments, you can `groupby` the index and return the `cumcount()` in a new object `s`. Then, you can groupby this new object `s` and get the `sum()`. I am assuming `index` is on your `index` in your example and not a column called `index`. If it is a column called `index`, then first do `df = df.set_index('index')`:

```
s = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df.groupby(s)['score'].sum()

0    6
1    9
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

If you print out `s`, then `s` looks like this:

```
    index
1    0
2    0
3    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
```