# How to sum columns while performing an inner merge?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to inner join while summing over two of their columns (COUNT1 and COUNT2)
For now I do it like so :

```
df_res = df1.merge(df2,on=['G-S'], how='inner')
print(df_res)
df_res['COUNT1']=df_res['COUNT1_x']+df_res['COUNT1_y']
df_res['COUNT2']=df_res['COUNT2_x']+df_res['COUNT2_y']
df_res=df_res.drop(columns=['COUNT1_x', 'COUNT1_y','COUNT2_x','COUNT2_y'])
```

But I want a one-liner when merging the two dataframes.
Example of input and output are below:

df1:

```
SOMEATT,COUNT1,COUNT2,G-S
B,53,31,SOMEVAL1
E,81,19,SOMEVAL1
L,90,20,SOMEVAL3
S,30,17,SOMEVAL2
```

df2:

```
SOMENUMBER,COUNT1,COUNT2,G-S
1,50,19,SOMEVAL1
7,32,16,SOMEVAL2
```

output:

```
SOMENUMBER,SOMEATT,COUNT1,COUNT2,G-S
    1,B,103,50,SOMEVAL1
    1,E,131,38,SOMEVAL1
    7,S,62,33,SOMEVAL2
```

PS: I don't want a solution with concat but ONLY with pd.merge()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(df1
 .merge(df2, on=['G-S'], how='inner')
 .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
 .groupby(level=0, axis=1, sort=False).sum())
```

output:

```
    SOMEATT COUNT1  COUNT2  G-S         SOMENUMBER
0   B       103     50      SOMEVAL1    1
1   E       131     38      SOMEVAL1    1
2   S       62      33      SOMEVAL2    7
```

If you want to change the order of the columns, use `reindex`

Comment: This code can be used if `_`(under bar) don exist in names of other columns.

Comment: what is level 0?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html chk `groupby` func

Comment: I saw, but what is levels?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263418/groupby-by-index-in-pandas then chk this post.  i have no more time to reply, have a good day

Comment: yes but isn't it the default param 0 for level?